# Prove that $\Bbb Z$ $\cong$ $n\Bbb Z$ for $n\not=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $\Bbb Z$ $\cong$ $n\Bbb Z$ for $n\not=0$

The group operation for both $\Bbb Z$ and $n\Bbb Z$ is addition
$$(\Bbb Z,o) and (n\Bbb Z,.) => (\Bbb Z,+) and (n\Bbb Z,+)$$

let's define the map $\phi$: $\Bbb Z$ to $n\Bbb Z$ with $n\not=0$, corresponding to the set of ordered pairs: $\{(1,n),(-1,-n),(2,2n),(-2,-2n),...,(b,bn),(a,an)\}$  where   $a$ and $n \not=0$ .

$$\phi(a+b)=n(a+b)=na+nb=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$$
$$\phi(a o b)=n(a+b)=na+nb=\phi(a).\phi(b)$$

Therefore the group operation is preserved.

Is this first part correct?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct so far. You could describe $\phi$ a bit more compactly, saying just "$\phi:\Bbb Z\to n\Bbb Z$ is given by $\phi(a)=an$" or something like that instead of listing all ordered pairs that make up the function. There are other small nit picks on how you've presented your proof, but overall you've done it correctly.

Comment: ok thx. I ll change that. I wrote those ordered pair to have a better picture. What about a? a can be any integer? I am working on proving that the function is bijective to complete the work it seems that $n /not= 0$ is the only necessary condition for the function to be bijective .